# Making a port as input in 8051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, assembler

As we all know in order to make a port input in 8051 we have to write FFH to that. That is,

```
MOV P1, #0FFH
```

after this execution does it mean all the pins of the port is set to high? In other word at that moment if I connect 8 LEDs to those pins will they turn on (though I know they have been configured as input port hence we should not try to use them as output port)? If no, then why

```
MOV P1,#0FFH
MOV A,P1
```

is making the accumulator FFH?

Comment: please don's say `As we all know ` because it is not true, we don't all know

Comment: `if I connect 8 LEDs to those pins` ... please draw a diagram of how the LEDs are connected

Comment: Positive pin of the LED is attached to the port pin, and negative pin is grounded.

Comment: imagine a switch between the output pin and ground ... that is how the output is wired ... the LED would not light .... the LED has to be connected between output and Vcc ..... google `open collector LED` ...... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=open+collector+led&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Which 8051? If you really mean the ancient original Intel 8051, then maybe, because it has open-drain IO pins.

Comment: The pseudo-bidirectional pins on the original NMOS 8051? Museum stuff. Modern 8051-core parts generally have fully bidirectional GPIOs.

Answer (score 3):

The standard 8051 has a quite simple port circuit on P1. Is it made from an open-drain output and a pull-up circuit. For example:

[image: (C)1995 Copyright Siemens]

The open-drain output is realized by `n3`. This transistor is capable to drain some current, refer to the data sheet of your controller. It drives the output "low" when you output a `0`.

`n1` and `n2` form the pull-up, providing some stronger current (`n1`) and some weaker current (`n2`) to a sink at the port pin. This way a "high" is output.

What is the reason for `n1` and its driving circuit? Well, if the output has to change from "low" to "high", it drives for 2 system clock cycles some more current. This way the raising edge at the output is shorter, because the inevitable parasitic capacitance is charged faster.

To use the pin as input, you will output a `1`. This opens `n3` and (after the 2 cycles mentioned above) lets `n2` provide the "high" level. If you leave the pin unconnected or floating, if will be read as `1`. If you source it with a "high", it will also be read as `1`. To input "low", your external signal source needs to drive the pin to ground. Refer to the data sheet to find out how much current you will need to safely get under the `0` threshold.

[image: (C)1995 Copyright Siemens]

In short:

- Output `0`: strong "low" to external circuit
- Output `1`: weak "high" to external circuit
- Output `1`, input "floating": read `1`
- Output `1`, input "high": read `1`
- Output `1`, input "low": read `0`